# Trying to get Captcha working alongside my validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation, xhtml, captcha

I have managed to validate my textboxes using JS but know I need to allow the captcha to work alongside the validation.

```
  <script>
  function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["reg"]["User"].value;
  var letters = "@";
  if (x.match(letters))
   { 
     alert("Can't Have Email Address As USERNAME!");
       return false;
      }

       return true;


    }
```

First Form

```
        <form name="reg" action="DBLogin.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

Captcha:

```
    <form action="validate.php" method="post">
      Enter Image Text
       <input name="captcha" type="text">
        <img src="captcha.php" /><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register">
      </form>
```

Is there a way of having the captcha work alongside my JS validation?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, simply use captcha... The JS validation is client side, PHP will validate the posted data (server-side)

Comment: What i want is for one button to be able to call the validate form as well as the js function form. So when the button is pressed it will validate the captcha as well the text fields, rather than having a seperate form/button for the captcha

Comment: Then bind an event listener to the submit button that takes care of the captcha, too... it's really not hard at all, if you know your way around JS events

Comment: The whole point of a `captcha` is that the data/question is obsquired on the browser so only a person can read it, and the answer is stored on the server. If you could validate the captcha on the browser then you would have to have access to the answer on the browser which means I could look at your html/javascript and know the answer. That would defeat the whole purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ajax to validate the captcha. and when he submits the form send an ajax request to verify captcha.

give a submit button only to the captcha form.

```html
<form id ="captcha-form" >
      Enter Image Text
       <input name="captcha" type="text">
        <img src="captcha.php" /><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

main form :

```html
<form id="main-form" name="reg" action="DBLogin.php" method="post">
  <!-- this shoulnt have an submit button -->
```

now use a js code to first verify the captcha and validate form

```js
$("#captcha-form").submit(function(event){
    
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);
    // let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    // serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "validate.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if(response == "true")
          {
            validateform();
          }
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // handle error
        
    });

    // callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

now the validate function

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["reg"]["User"].value;
  var letters = "@";
  if (x.match(letters))
   { 
     alert("Can't Have Email Address As USERNAME!");
       
      }

       $("#main-form").submit();


    }
```

as RiggsFolly has pointed out this is not recommended. as this would defeat the purpose of captcha.